# How large is the memory size of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have this code:

`var prop = $ ('body);`

Does the 'prop' allocate more memory space or is it just referencing the element?

Comment: Depends on what the `$` function does..  Is it jquery?.

Comment: function $(key){
  return document.getElementById(key);
}

Comment: Then prop is just a reference to a DOM node..

Comment: Is there any documentation or any place that says this? would be very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

"prop" in your example is just a reference object. It only occupies space to store information like location of element in the DOM, element properties and inherited functions.